# Проверка работоспособности Net Framework

Tags: .net

Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ(ы) проверки наличия в системе установленных версий .NET Framework, и какой-либо **надежный** способ(ы) проверки их корректного функционирования.

В частности, пока очень нужна проверка версии 2.0 для Windows10-x64.

Пока в сети нашел несколько примеров на VBS (типа [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394607/vbscript-to-check-if-net-2-0-is-installed)), но тестами их назвать сложно - там простая проверка ключей реестра. Хотелось бы чего-то более существенного.

**О "более существенной" проверке**

Нужна программа, которая последовательно делает вызовы из .NET (в соответствии с версиями), и если по каким-то причинам вызовы завершаются ошибкой - это должно отображаться в результатах.

Простой пример. .NET 3.5 установлен, но одна из динамических библиотек была удалена - пусть работа вируса, к примеру. По факту и каталоги есть, и в реестре все прописано - но работоспособность нарушена. Вот эту проверку я называю "более существенной".

Comment: _Хотелось бы чего-то более существенного._ - например?

Comment: Допустим программа, которая последовательно делает вызовы из .NET (в соответствии с версиями), и если по каким-то причинам вызовы завершаются ошибкой - это должно отображаться в результатах. Простой пример: .NET 3.5 установлен, но одна из динамических библиотек была удалена - пусть работа вируса, к примеру. По факту и каталоги есть, и в реестре все прописано - но работоспособность нарушена. Вот эту проверку я называю "более существенной"

Comment: стоит добавить это описание в сам вопрос

Comment: Описание добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вручную проверку можно выполнить с помощью утилиты [netfx_setupverifier](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmandreev/2010/10/20/703/) от MS. Правда, лично я, искал консольную утилиту для реализации автоматической проверки.

Answer (score 2):

Сам Microsoft рекомендует (по крайней мере про это статья на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx) есть), как один из вариантов, смотреть в реестре.

> To find .NET Framework versions by viewing the registry (.NET Framework 1-4)
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP

---

> To find .NET Framework versions by viewing the registry (.NET Framework 4.5 and later)
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full

можно это проверять или через regedit.exe или через cmd, к примеру

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP" | findstr "v2.0*"
```

выдаст:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727

Ну или через код, как в вашем варианте или как в статье с MSDN описано

---

**UPD**

Сборки лежат в GAC по пути %windir%\assembly для .NET < 4. Можно пытаться их проверять по наименованию, например. Но зачем?